# Trying to find a Ranma 1/2 fanfic where they wind up in the real world

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, ranma-one-half

One of those weird things that popped into my head. I read a *Ranma 1/2* fanfic somewhere in the late 1990s to the early 2000s which had the cast somehow winding up in the "real world" that we live in, where they're fictional characters.

Specifically, they showed up nearby a convention center, and were initially mistaken for cosplayers (I don't remember if a "[your costume needs work](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YourCostumeNeedsWork)" joke was made). They're befriended by a group of convention-goers who might have been self-inserts of the writers. Unfortunately, this having been decades ago, my one firm memory is that the cast, which at least included Ranma himself, but may have included others, could still perform superhuman feats, but physics caught up with them, with Ranma performing the *[Kachū Tenshin Amaguriken](https://ranma.fandom.com/wiki/Kach%C5%AB_Tenshin_Amaguriken)* and after a moment of his hands blurring through the movements, he's suddenly thrown backwards with burnt hands due to the combination of a sonic boom from air displacement and air friction kicking in.

I remember the story being written in English, with good enough spelling and grammar that I don't remember it being horrible. I might have read it on the FFML, the FanFic Mailing List.

Comment: It had good spelling and not had grammar? That rules out about 100% of FFML content.

Comment: ^_^ Sturgeon's Law suggests that 10% of the content is at least OK.

Comment: this is my first time learning about ffml and oh boi what an interesting concept. I found the archive but after looking through a few random months, I'd feel it would take me forever to sift/understand everything to find the right fics (for your other ffml question too). I might take another crack at it when I have more time but if you have time and wanna have at it, here's the archive I found.  https://www.fanfics.dev/

Comment: Are you sure you didn't dream about this? Because it definitely sounds like something I could have dreamt up.